# How do i access git gist from visual studio code(pull/push)?

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-code, gist

I want to save my code snippets in the git gist for quicker references. But i want to access it from my ide Visaul Studio Code as well. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Possibly https://help.github.com/articles/forking-and-cloning-gists/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install Gist extension for VS code:

VS code -> Extensions -> search Gist -> install the extension (such as install the extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kenhowardpdx.vscode-gist for below example) -> after install successful -> reload.

[image]

Then you can save your code to Gist through VS code directly:

Open the file you want to save in Gist -> press <kbd>F1</kbd> -> input `Gist: create new block` -> input description etc.

To open/edit a relate Gist, you can press <kbd>F1</kbd>, and input `GIST: Open Block`.

Note: for the first time when creating Gist by VS code, you need to provide your github username and password.